# Limit Comparison Test - ex. prob wrong?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm doing some practice problems on the Limit Comparison test from this site:
http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/6/series.14/index.html

But I'm a bit confused on this problem: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (\frac 1n)$ .

The solution says to use the harmonic series for comparison ( $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n $ ),

which, when set up for the limit test gives (this is the solution from the webpage): $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin (\frac 1n)}{\frac 1n} = 1$$

What I don't understand is how they solved the limit. The $\sin (\frac 1\infty$) makes sense, since it goes to $\sin(0) = 0$, but the bottom half of the fraction is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n = \frac 1\infty = 0$, which would result in $\frac {\sin(0)}0 $, which by my understanding would be a divide by zero error.

Changing the form to $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin(\frac 1n)$ also appears to be a dead end since I just get $\infty \sin(\frac 1\infty)$.

What am I missing here? How can the above limit evaluate to 1? I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (\frac 1n) $ is divergent, as is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n $, and so I would expect the LCT to give a finite, positive value confirming this, but I guess I don't understand how they did their limit evaluation. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the transformation  $ \ u \ = \frac{1}{n} \ $ , so that you can write the limit as  $ \ \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{\sin u}{u} \ $ , which has a (supposedly) familiar result.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thank you! Just to clarify, the reason that the limit used in the substitution goes to 0 is because the original limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac 1n) = 0$ ?

Comment: The problem is that having $ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \ +\infty} \ \frac{1}{n} \ = 0 $ doesn't tell us much: not failing the "Test for Divergence" doesn't mean an infinite series converges.  The "Limit Comparison Test" tells us that if $ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{a_n}{b_n} \ $ is a positive constant, then the infinite series $ \ \sum \ a_n \ $ and $ \ \sum \ b_n \ $ either both converge or both diverge.  By finding that the limit of the ratio you wrote is 1, _and_ knowing that the harmonic series _diverges_, we can conclude that $ \ \sum^{\infty} \ \sin(\frac{1}{n}) \ $ also diverges.

Comment: To answer your comment question, we make the substitution so that we can make use of the known limit for $ \ \frac{\sin u}{u} \ $ .  The fact that the limit in the denominator of that ratio, $ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \frac{1}{n} \ $ , is zero is troublesome and means we can't simply use the "limit laws".  So instead, we have to use a known trigonometric limit.